# odd behavior while looping over an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm reading through Eloquent Javascript and facing one of the exercises, I found a rather odd behavior. (at least for me)

the exercise asks to create a function in order to reverse an array. I thought I could loop over the array and each time pop one item from the original array and push it into a temporary array that is going to finally be returned.
but as I'm looping over the array either with a for-of loop or typical sequential loop, last item is not transferred.

can someone tell me what happens exactly?

```
const reverseArray = function(array) {
let rev = [];
for (let x = 0; x <= array.length; x++) {

    rev.push(array.pop());
    console.log(rev, array)
}
return rev;
};


console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```

output:

```
["C"] ["A", "B"]
["C", "B"] ["A"]
["C", "B"]
```

Comment: You should also be mindful of the "off by one bug" (obob) when using `i <= array.length` this answer will illustrate this point: [obob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939869/what-is-exactly-the-off-by-one-errors-in-the-while-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `pop()` applies on `array` it decreases the length of the `array` so when the loop runs it finds one item less than the previous array length. Thus, what you can do is simply assign the length of the `array` in a variable and use that in the comparison of the `for` loop:

```js
let rev = [];
const reverseArray = function(array) {
var length = array.length;
for (let x = 0; x < length; x++) {
  rev.push(array.pop());
}
return rev;
};


console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! now I get it.

Answer (score 3):

As the [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method remove the *pop'ed* item from the array, use a `while` loop instead of `for`

```js
let rev = [];
const reverseArray = function(array) {
    while (array.length > 0) {    // or just "(array.length)"
      rev.push(array.pop());
    }
    return rev;
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```

With `closure` you can save yourself an extra global variable

```js
const reverseArray = function(array) {
  return (function(a_in,a_out) {
    while (a_in.length > 0) {    // or just "(a_in.length)"
      a_out.push(a_in.pop());
    }
    return a_out;
  })(array,[]);
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```

Or if the `Array.reverse()` method is allowed

```js
const reverseArray = function(array) {
    return array.reverse();
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [**pop()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method removes the last element of an array, and returns that element. It changes the length of an array.

```js
const popArray = function(array) {
  for (let x = 0; x <= array.length; x++) {
      console.log("value of x :", x);
      console.log("array.length :", array.length);
      array.pop();
      console.log("array after", x + 1, "pop :", array);
  }
};

popArray(["A", "B", "C"]);
```

In the above `demo` we can see that everytime pop() happens on an array. `array.length` will decrease and value of `x` will be increase. Hence, At certain point of time (after 2nd iteration) value of `x` will be `greater` then the length of an array.

Use **Array.from()** method :

```js
let rev = [];
const reverseArray = function(array) {
  var destinationArray = Array.from(array);
  for (var i in Array.from(array)) {
    rev.push(array.pop());
    console.log(rev, array);
  }
};


reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using while loop instead of for loop

```
const reverseArray = function(array){                                       
let rev = [];                                                             
while (array.length>0)                                                        
{                           
rev.push(array.pop());                                                       
}                                                  
return rev;                                                                  
};                                             
console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I put two versions for you. `reverse` will reverse the array without modifying the original array. `reverseModify` will do the same, but emptying the original array.

Choose the version that suits you better

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function reverse(array) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result.push(array[i]);
  }
  
  return result;
}

function reverseModify(array) {
  let result = [];
  while (array.length) {
    result.push(array.pop());
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(reverse(arr), arr);
console.log(reverseModify(arr), arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is divides into two independent operations.

1. iterate all elements, usually take the length and perform a loop
2. `pop` a value and `push that value. This is the mechanism to take the last`item and push it to the end of the new array.

The part for iterating needs only the actual length and a count down (by `pop`) to zero and then exit the loop.

For a count up, you need two vvariables, one for the counter and one for the end or length of the array, which is a static value, take from the given array, which is later mutating.

```js
function reverseArray(array) {
    var rev = [];
  
    while (array.length) {
        rev.push(array.pop());
    }
    return rev;
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```