# Why Java script giving error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to fill the form and display the form data using table format but I am getting the error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

I have added all my HTML, CSS, and js code below. When I see the console I see error code executes correctly.

I found the error is because I have <= used in the for loop. when I use just < error goes away. What is the theory behind this?

Please help me

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                            div#result {
                                        width: 100%;
                                        clear: both;
                                        text-align: center;
                           }
                           #result div {
                                        width: 25%;
                                        float: left;
                           }
            </style>
            <title>Contact form</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function(){ 
                var users = [];
                var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
                var form = document.querySelector("#form");
        
                 btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        
                    var obj ={
        
                        name: document.querySelector('#name').value,
                        email: document.querySelector('#email').value,
                        phone: document.querySelector('#phone').value,
                        website: document.querySelector('#website').value,
        
        
                    //console.log(obj);
                    }
                     
                    users.push(obj);
                    console.log(users);
                    var output = document.querySelector('#output');  //getElementById was giving error 
                    output.innerHTML = "<h1> Result </h1>";
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.setAttribute('id', 'result');
                    output.appendChild(div);
        
                    
        
                    for(var i =0; i<=  users.length; i++){
        
                        
                    //div.innerHTML = "";
                    div.innerHTML  += "<div>" + users[i].name + "</div>" + 
                                         "<div>" + users[i].email + "</div>" + 
                                         "<div>" + users[i].phone + "</div>" +
                                         "<div>" + users[i].website + "</div>" ;    
                    
        
                    form.reset();
                    }
        
                        
                 })
                    
                
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="input">
            <h1> Form </h1>
        <form id="form">
        
            <p><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required></p>
        
            <p><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" required></p>
        
            <p><input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required></p>
        
            <p><input type="website" name="website" id="website" placeholder="www.example.com" required></p>
        
            <p><input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit"></p>
        </form>
            </div>
        <br>
            <div id="output">
                 
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: `i<=` should be `i<`

Comment: In the duplicate listed at the top of your question, [see this answer specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57539801/479156). Only in JavaScript, you don't get an "index out of bounds error", but when you select an index that is out of bounds, it will return `undefined`. And as the error tells you, you "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".