# TypeError: Cannot read property 'variable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting this `undefined` error in my node js written program. This was the line that was causing the issue

```
sockets[index].notification = 1;
```

So in order to resolve this, I did this

```
if ( typeof sockets[index].notification !== 'undefined' ) {
                              
   sockets[index].notification = 1;
 }
```

But it still gave the same error

```
if ( typeof sockets[index].notification_acc_on !== 'undefined' ) {
                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'notification' of undefined
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/server.js:506:56)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

How can I check and handle this so if the variable isn't set, my program doesn't crash at least? In short I want to prevent the crash

Comment: The error states "Cannot read property 'notification' ***of*** undefined". You are reading `notification` of `sockets[index]`. `sockets[index]` is `undefined`. Not `sockets[index].notification`. That being said it sounds like an [off-by-one error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939869/what-is-an-off-by-one-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem is with `sockets[index]` being undefined.

```
if ( typeof sockets[index] !== 'undefined' ) {
                              
   sockets[index].notification = 1;
}
```

There are other checks you might consider exploring, for example checking for null value, confirming that `sockets` exists, etc. My response only deals with the immediate problem from the original post.

Comment: The variable `sockets` can itself be `undefined`, in which case your code will also fail.

Comment: @sfuqua I am sorry so what is the solution here?

Comment: @MaksymShcherban sockets variable has been defined globally.

Comment: In this revision, we check that the object returned by `[index]` is not undefined, whereas in your original you are checking a property _on_ that object.

Comment: @sfuqua Oh I am sorry got it thank you

Answer (score 0):

You reveive this error because either `sockets` or `sockets[index]` is `undefined`. To avoid this error, you can perform the following check:

```js
if (typeof sockets?.[index] !== 'undefined') {
}
```

Comment: okay, Let me implement this. thank you for the answer