# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onclick' - Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

Who know what is the error i don't understand why throws error, I try in to the console, and the code works...

```
var array_Hilos_FOROMAESTRO = [];
var array_cantidad_FOROS = [];

async function fncCalcularEntradas() {
    var array_Hilos_FOROMAESTRO = [];
    var array_cantidad_FOROS = [];
    //consulta foros 
    var consulta = document.evaluate(xpath_consulta_FOROS, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var consultaIter = consulta.iterateNext();
    while(consultaIter){
        array_cantidad_FOROS.push(consultaIter)
        consultaIter = consulta.iterateNext();
    }
    //consulta hilos
    var hilos = document.evaluate(xpath_temas_FOROMAESTRO, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var hilosIter = hilos.iterateNext();
    while(hilosIter){
        array_Hilos_FOROMAESTRO.push(hilosIter);
        hilosIter = hilos.iterateNext();
    }
    for (let index = 0; index <= array_Hilos_FOROMAESTRO.length; index++) {
        array_Hilos_FOROMAESTRO[index].onclick()
        fncCopiaForo();
        for(let i = 0; i < array_cantidad_FOROS.length ; i++){
          if(array_cantidad_FOROS[i].classname =='submenu_link active'){
              array_cantidad_FOROS[i].onlick();
          }  
        }   
    }
}
```

The error throws:
`VM53337:97 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onclick')     at fncCalcularEntradas (<anonymous>:97:40)     at MensajesForo (<anonymous>:112:9)     at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an off-by-one error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939869/what-is-an-off-by-one-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It means your `array_Hilos_FOROMAESTRO` array is empty. So the first element (element 0) is undefined. You can't do `undefined.onclick()`.

Comment: But i writing in to the array at line array_Hilos_FOROMAESTRO.push(hilosIter);

Comment: @JeremyThille I'd argue that the problem is the condition of the for loop. They have `index <= array_Hilos_FOROMAESTRO.length` causing the array to iterate one too many times. It doesn't necessarily have to be empty. (It _might_ be, but fixing the condition will resolve the error in that case as well.)

Comment: @Ivar I just try, and you have reason is that <=, i just fix replace then <

Comment: @Ivar that's correct