# How to init a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use List to store my data, but the compiler says "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

how can I init the list like myvector3 = new Vector3[65];

I use

public Vector3[] myvector3;

public Quaternion[] myQuaternion;

then

myvector3 = new Vector3[65];

myQuaternion = new Quaternion[65];

is ok....

```
public List<GameObject> Stroeallobject;
public List<Vector3> myvector3;
public List<Quaternion> myQuaternion;

private void Start()
{
for (int i = 0; i < Stroeallobject.Count; i++)
{
  myvector3[i] = Stroealljoint[i].transform.position;
  myQuaternion[i] = Stroealljoint[i].transform.rotation;
}
}
```

Comment: [What is an off-by-one error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939869/what-is-an-off-by-one-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the list variable with

```
public List<Vector3> myvector3;
```

but it's null after that, because you didn't assign it anything. You can make a new empty list later with

```
myvector3 = new List<Vector3>();
```

and you can also give it a *capacity* so it doesn't need to keep dynamically resizing the list as you add things to it:

```
myvector3 = new List<Vector3>(65);
```

but setting the *capacity* doesn't make anything. You're just saying you need the *space* for 65 Vector3 entries in the list. You can't assign anything into an index at this point because the list is empty.

It's not until you `.Add()` something to the list that you're allowed to index into it. This is different than an array.

Fortunately it's an easy fix for your code - change the index operation to an Add (and initialize the List) and you should be good to go!

```
public List<GameObject> Stroeallobject;
public List<Vector3> myvector3;
public List<Quaternion> myQuaternion;

private void Start()
{
    myvector3 = new List<Vector3>(); // Can use Stroealljoint.Count for capacity if you want
    myQuaternion = new List<Quaternion>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Stroeallobject.Count; i++)
    {
        myVector3. Add(Stroealljoint[i].transform.position);
        myQuaternion.Add(Stroealljoint[i].transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike an array, a `List<>` doesn't need to be initialized to a given length.  You can simply instantiate it:

```
public List<Vector3> myvector3 = new List<Vector3>();
```

(Though it seems from the specific error message that is already being done elsewhere?  Otherwise I would have expected a `NullReferenceException`.  But either way...)

And then add items to it:

```
myvector3.Add(Stroealljoint[i].transform.position);
```

(The same is true of the other `List<>` object(s) of course.)